# Different manifest location on Puppet Server/Agent

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

My Puppet Server Environment setting is as follows

```
[master]
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /data/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
codedir = /data/puppetlabs/code

#  puppet master --configprint manifest
/data/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```

On Agents it is as follows

```
server = jw-host
environment = production
```

But --configprint is showing a different location on agent nodes

```
# puppet master --configprint manifest
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```

It is not getting changed to /data because of which my manifests are not getting applied .

Versions are as follows

```
 # puppetserver  --version
  puppetserver version: 2.4.0
 # puppet  --version
  4.5.2
```

What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the `puppet master --configprint` checks locally which settings a puppet server would use.
It does not connect to the configured master and get the value from it.

As you are not running a puppet server on the agent this setting is not relevant.
It is simply defaulting to `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests` when it's not set at all.
But it's anyway not used by the agent.